Patch related table with collection from another table. "Specified column not accessible in this context"
I have 3 tables - Employee, EmployeeSoftware, Software. Employee and Software have a one-to-many relationship with EmployeeSoftware and it is intended to be a bridge table. In my canvas app, I am creating a collection based on the software that is selected in a gallery. (gallery displays all software) I have a submit button that would ideally patch each selected Software and Employee to the EmployeeSoftware table. However, when trying to use a ForAll(collection, I get an error that EmployeeSoftwares is not accessible in this context.
ForAll(SelectedItems,
Patch('EmployeeSoftwares', Defaults(EmployeeSoftwares) ....
Is there a better way I could achieve this outcome or how could I make the collection patch to a seperate table?

Ensure the EmployeeSoftwares Table is Added as a Data Source, by applying the following

Go to the Data Sources panel in Power Apps, Confirm that EmployeeSoftwares is added as a data source.
If it’s not listed, add it by selecting Add Data and choosing the table.

